# Can't delete exe file even when no users are using it

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I have a very simple C# application. I copy the exe file other to a shared directory where my team (only 4 of us) can use the app.

A recent problem is this, we need to update the app. So I create a new app. I then delete the exe file from the shared directory and the exe file is no longer there however if I refresh the directory it comes back. No of the other users have it open? This stops me copying over the new version.

Why is this happening? How can I check if anyone does have the app open? As you can probably tell from my post I'm not overly technical. Any help would be great.

Comment: Possible anti virus is still playing with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to see what locks your file and kill it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have to check it later sadly as my work had blocked the link

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, find the process that has the open handle, and then close that process.

You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)  or the [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) command to determine which process is using the file.